# Signed Hmac/sha1 message using Go different result than node.js or Python

Tags: go, hmac, hmacsha1

I am trying to generate a Hmac/SHA1 signature using Go, but I'm getting different results than when I test with Node.js or Python.

Here's my code in Go:

```
signature := hmac.New(sha1.New, []byte(signKey))
signature.Write([]byte(buffer))
return hex.EncodeToString(signature.Sum(nil))
```

Here's my code in Node.js:

```
return crypto.createHmac('sha1', signKey).update(buffer).digest('hex');
```

Python:

```
return hmac.new(signKey, buffer, sha1).hexdigest()
```

Can you help figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am getting identical results in Go and Node.js in my testing. That means that your key and/or buffer **must** different in Go.

Here is my test code for reference:

Go:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/sha1"
    "encoding/hex"
)

func main() {
    signKey := "12345"
    buffer := []byte{1, 2, 3}
    signature := hmac.New(sha1.New, []byte(signKey))
    signature.Write([]byte(buffer))
    println(hex.EncodeToString(signature.Sum(nil)))
}
```

Node.js:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var signKey = "12345";
var buffer  = "\x01\x02\x03";
console.log(
    crypto.createHmac('sha1', signKey).update("\x01\x02\x03", "binary").digest('hex')
);
```